# How to remove all frontend files from Loopback app

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback4

While developing on a loopback api it is very convenient that the default `lp4 app` command generates a simple landing page with a swagger api explorer.

But I don't want this when I am finished. where in the code do I disable the self hosted pages, and which files should I delete to remove irrelevant files in my project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are **4** artifacts that you may want to individually disabled/removed:

1. **Default `/` landing page:** The default page that links to `openapi.json` and the API explorer.
2. **Externally-hosted REST explorer redirect:** A redirect from `/swagger-ui` and `/explorer` to a REST explorer that's hosted elsewhere (e.g. https://explorer.loopback.io).
3. **Self-hosted REST explorer:** A REST explorer served at `/explorer`. Takes precedence over hosted REST explorer redirect for `/explorer` path by default.
4. **OpenAPI spec endpoint:** The OpenAPI 3.0 spec hosted at `/openapi.json` by default.

Although the instructions here can be followed exactly for majority of LoopBack 4 projects, more customised projects may have certain things (e.g. application or component configuration) moved around.

---

**To remove the default `/` landing page:**

1. Remove the `public` directory
2. Remove the following lines from `src/application.ts`:

   ```js
   // Set up default home page
   this.static('/', path.join(__dirname, '../public'));
   ```

---

**To disable externally-hosted REST explorer through configuration:**

1. In `src/index.ts`, configure `config.rest.apiExplorer.disabled`:

   ```js
   const config = {
     rest: {
       apiExplorer: {
         disabled: true,
       },
     },
   };
   ```

---

**To completely remove self-hosted REST explorer:**

1. Remove the following lines from `application.ts`:

   ```js
   // Customize @loopback/rest-explorer configuration here
   this.configure(RestExplorerBindings.COMPONENT).to({
     path: '/explorer',
   });
   this.component(RestExplorerComponent);
   ```
2. Uninstall `@loopback/rest-explorer`

---

**To disable the OpenAPI spec endpoint through configuration:**

1. In `src/index.ts`, configure `config.rest.openApiSpec.disabled`:

   ```js
   const config = {
     rest: {
       openApiSpec: {
         disabled: true,
       },
     },
   };
   ```

Note that disabling the OpenAPI spec endpoint would prevent the REST explorers from working correctly as they are dependent on an web browser-accessible OpenAPI spec.

Disabling the OpanAPI spec endpoint does not disable access to the OpenAPI spec from within TypeScript nor does it affect AJV validation.

### References

- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Customizing-server-configuration.html#disable-redirect-to-api-explorer
- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Customizing-server-configuration.html#rest-options
- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/Self-hosted-rest-api-explorer.html#disable-self-hosted-api-explorer
- https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb4/apidocs.rest.openapispecoptions.html